# Atualizar gatilho de plugin jquery ao atualizar imagem via DOM

Tags: jquery, dom, lightbox

Fiz uma galeria em HTML5 e CSS3 e inseri um plugin Jquery "LightGallery" para abrir as imagens em tamanho maior como lightbox, existe uma imagem grande e várias miniaturas, quando clico em uma miniatura a maior é substituída pela imagem grande da thumbnail, mas o plugin carregado não reconhece a nova imagem dentro do atributo, tem algum modo de atualizar o gatilho do plugin para que ele reconheça o novo caminho da imagem que foi atualizada?

```
<html>
<body>

<img id="imgDestaqueShow" data-src="caminho-da-imagem/grande1.jpg" src="caminho-da-imagem/pequena1.jpg" class="light-link">

<img data-src="caminho-da-imagem/grande2.jpg" src="caminho-da-imagem/pequena2.jpg" class="thumbnail-gallery">

<img data-src="caminho-da-imagem/grande3.jpg" src="caminho-da-imagem/pequena3.jpg" class="thumbnail-gallery">

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#lightgallery").lightGallery({
    selector: '.light-link'
});

$(".thumbnail-gallery").on('click', function(){
    var transferImg = $(this).attr('data-src');
    $("#imgDestaqueShow").attr('src',transferImg);
    $("#imgDestaqueShow").attr('data-src',transferImg);
});

});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tem como vc colocar o código completo para tentar reproduzir?

Comment: Por favor poste o código completo (Todas pastas e bibliotecas) para que possamos ver seu problema e o ajudar.